# structuremap Property Injection

Tags: dependency-injection, mocking, structuremap

How to do Dependency Injection on Property of a class Using Structure Map

```
public class ContactController : Controller
{
    public IContactService Service { get; set; }

    public ContactController()
        : this(null,null)
    {
    }

    [SetterProperty]
    public MembershipProvider Provider { get; private set; }
}
```

Here when i Create instance of ContactController i want provider to be set to `Mock<MembershipProvider>`  please help me how to go about doing this? Mock is Moq Framework class

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a Mock, you are most likely writing test code. If thats the case, you likely don't need a dependency injection tool like StructureMap involved. Just set the Provider property manually to your MembershpProvider in your test setup code.

```
controller.Provider = Mock<MembershipProvider>
```

If you really want to configure setter injection using StructureMap, see this answer:
[Property Injection into an Action Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876436/property-injection-into-an-action-filter/3877567#3877567)