# Initialize Object Properties

Tags: structuremap

I am injecting in my services a global Settings interface, as Singleton, using StructureMap:

```
public interface ISettings {
  LoggerSettings Logger { get; }
} // ISettings

public class LoggerSettings {
  public String Levels { get { return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Logger.Levels"]; } }
  public const String Report = "team@xyz.com";
} // LoggerSettings

public class Settings : ISettings {
  public LoggerSettings Logger { get; private set; }
} // Settings
```

And as SM configuration I have:

```
For<ISettings>().Singleton().Use<Settings>();
```

I am able to inject this object but when I check the injected object its property Logger is null ... How can I have SM to initialize the object properties?

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a constructor on the `Settings` class that has a `LoggerSettings` parameter so that StructureMap can set the Logger property on creation.

If you for some reason can't/don't want to use Constructor injection you need to make the setter on the `Logger` property on the `Settings` class public and [configure property injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979453/structuremap-beginner-property-injection) in StructureMap.

**TL;DR**: make `Settings` look like this:

```
public class Settings : ISettings {
    public Settings(LoggerSettings logger)
    {
         Logger = logger;
    }

    public LoggerSettings Logger { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: Don't I need to have a ILoggerSettings and a LoggerSettings?

Comment: No, it should work without an interface. StructureMap will create instances of concrete classes as long as it can resolve all the dependencies. If you wish to be able to change the implementation of the LoggerSettings (for testability, etc) you need an interface though or make the properties settable.