# Structuremap and generics for open generic type

Tags: c#, generics, inversion-of-control

Have the following Interface

```
public interface IFoo<T> : IComparable<IPayRecordField<T>> where T : IComparable
```

I want auto fill all properties of IFoo with the implementation Foo. Using Structuremap

EXample

```
class SomeClass
{
   IFoo<string> MyFoo {get; set;} //this should be autofilled by structuremap with an instance of Foo<string>
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use constructor injection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's actually rather simple. You can map an open genric interface to an open generic implementation just as you would register any other type:

```cs
container.Configure(r => r
    .For(typeof(IFoo<>))
    .Use(typeof(Foo<>)));
```

StructureMap will automatically resolve a `Foo<SomeType>` when you request a `IFoo<SomeType>`.

Comment: Yep thats for a new instance. But how do I do a property injection into SomeClass So MyFoo is set automagically with Foo<string>

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979453/structuremap-beginner-property-injection

Comment: I cant see how that works for generics?

Comment: There are `FillAllPropertiesOfType` and `Setter` methods to allow property injection on either a single type (Setter) or all types (FillAllPropertiesOfType), but unfortunately there are only generic overloads available. So the only thing you can do is mark the `MyFoo` property with an `[SetterProperty]` attribute. Not pretty, but it will do the trick.