# How do I set a property on a base class for all classes that subclass it, using structuremap?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, structuremap

I have numerous (60 or 70) classes that subclass a shared base class. This base class exposes a property of type `ICacheProvider` that needs to be set when each of the superclasses is registered with structuremap. I am using structuremap version 2.6.1. Currently, I am setting the property for each superclass, thus:

```
        For<IBusinessRule<IEnumerable<int>>>()
            .Use<ManufacturersWithReviewsRule>()
            .Named(NamedRuleConstants.ManufacturersWithReviews)
            .Setter<ICacheProvider>().Is(ObjectFactory.GetNamedInstance<ICacheProvider>(CacheConstants.IndexCacheKeyPrefix));

        For<IBusinessRule<IEnumerable<int>>>()
            .Use<ManufacturersWithOwnersReviewsRule>()
            .Named(NamedRuleConstants.ManufacturersWithOwnersReviews)
            .Setter<ICacheProvider>().Is(ObjectFactory.GetNamedInstance<ICacheProvider>(CacheConstants.IndexCacheKeyPrefix));

        For<IBusinessRule<IEnumerable<int>>>()
            .Use<ManufacturersWithLivingWithItRule>()
            .Named(NamedRuleConstants.ManufacturersWithLivingWithIt)
            .Setter<ICacheProvider>().Is(ObjectFactory.GetNamedInstance<ICacheProvider>(CacheConstants.IndexCacheKeyPrefix));
```

(ManufacturersWithReviewsRule, ManufacturersWithOwnersReviewsRule, ManufacturersWithLivingWithItRule each subclass BaseBusinessRule)

What I want to do is specify the:

```
.Setter<ICacheProvider>().Is(ObjectFactory.GetNamedInstance<ICacheProvider>(CacheConstants.IndexCacheKeyPrefix));
```

a single time for all, allowing me to set it individually where necessary should I require a different ICacheProvider.

Is this possible using structuremap 2.6.1? I can find no way of doing it.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9549409/20047 and the linked post (http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2009/01/16/creating-policies-for-setter-injection-in-structuremap/)

Comment: My first impression is that you should ditch the base class completely and implement caching (a cross cutting concern) using a decorator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a similar concept, when I want to set any object having some type of property on a default level, I use something like this

```
// during the ObjectFactory.Initialize
x.SetAllProperties(set => set.OfType<ICacheProvider>());

// something more...
// this way the instance could be shared 
x.For<ICacheProvider>()
    // as a singleton
    .Singleton()
    .Use<DefaultCacheProvider>();
```