# Forcing a class to have a constructor

Tags: c#, class, constructor

How can I force a class have a specified constructor signature without using abstract classes?
I googled and found that we couldn't use interfaces to do it.

**[Updated]**

e.g, I have the the following `Interface`:

```
public interface IListView<TViewModel, TListQueryParameter, TSingleQueryParameter>
    where TListQueryParameter : IQueryParameter<IEnumerable<TViewModel>>, new()
    where TSingleQueryParameter : IQueryParameter<TViewModel>
{
    ...
    IQueryHandler<TListQueryParameter, IEnumerable<TViewModel>> FindListDataQueryHandler { get; }
    IQueryHandler<TSingleQueryParameter, TViewModel> FindSingleEntityQueryHandler { get; }
    ...
}
```

and I want to inject `QueryHandler`s using constructor of each `Form` that implement the `IListView`.

Comment: could you describe your actual use case?

Comment: Why do you need it? That will help you to get better answers

Comment: seems a bit overly complex.....?

Comment: Don't your IOC supports property injection?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: I'm using structuremap.

Comment: It should not be the responsibility of `IListView` to enforce ctor injection over property injection.

Comment: http://docs.structuremap.net/ConstructorAndSetterInjection.htm#section6

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979453/structuremap-beginner-property-injection might also help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like structuremap does supports property injection [here](http://docs.structuremap.net/ConstructorAndSetterInjection.htm#section6) and [here](http://docs.structuremap.net/ConstructorAndSetterInjection.htm#section12), that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to inject a dependency, then use a Dependency Injection system or a DI resolver. This is called property injection. Try UNITY or Ninject.